# Is is possible to load many meshes in Meshlab and display them one at a time?

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to create a procedure for doctors to annotate 3D craniofacial scans in the form of obj files using Meshlab. Ideally, I would like to load a bunch of obj files from a directory into Meshlab at once, then be able to see the one craniofacial scan at a time. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

A very useful option is pressing **control** (command on mac) while clicking on the "*eye*": the clicked mesh is made visible and all the other ones are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Open MeshLab and hit ctrl+I or go to File > Import mesh

You can select multiple files at a time. The "eye" next to each mesh in the project window at the top right allows you to turn the visibility of each mesh on or off.